# I'm trying to use multiple nested np.where to create a column of a data frame in python ,facing error on the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Consider a data frame with 97 rows and 44 columns where i have three columns whose names are "Bostwick","mu_yield" , so i'm trying to create a new column called "Target" where if the "Bostwick" column values lie between "5.00 and 6.75" else if "mu_yield" column values lie between
"89.00 and 90.00" , the "Target" column values should be 0 else it is 1

I tried the below way

```
bos['Target'] = np.where(((bos['mu_yield'] < 5.000) | (bos['mu_yield'] > 6.750)), 0, 
                         np.where((bos['mu_yield'] < 89.00) | (bos['mu_yield'] > 90.00), 0, 1)))
```

There were no errors but the entire "Target" column values are 0

Hence i tried the below method

```
bos['Target'] = np.where((bos['Bostwick'] < 5.000) | (bos['Bostwick'] > 6.750)) or ((bos['mu_yield'] < 89.00) | (bos['mu_yield'] > 90.00), 0, 1)
```

Here i'm facing the below value error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_35620/4282921525.py in <module>
----> 1 bos['Target'] = np.where((bos['Bostwick'] < 5.000) | (bos['Bostwick'] > 6.750)) or ((bos['mu_yield'] < 89.00) | (bos['mu_yield'] > 90.00), 0, 1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3610         else:
   3611             # set column
-> 3612             self._set_item(key, value)
   3613 
   3614     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3782         ensure homogeneity.
   3783         """
-> 3784         value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3785 
   3786         if (

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, value)
   4507 
   4508         if is_list_like(value):
-> 4509             com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
   4510         return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)
   4511 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    529     """
    530     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 531         raise ValueError(
    532             "Length of values "
    533             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (94)
```

Requesting someone to help me on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise OR and in original use `&` for bitwise  `AND`:

```
bos['Target'] = np.where(((bos['Bostwick'] > 5.000) & (bos['Bostwick'] < 6.750)) |
                         ((bos['mu_yield'] > 89.00) & (bos['mu_yield'] < 90.00)), 0, 1)
```

Alternative with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
bos['Target1'] = np.where(bos['Bostwick'].between(5.000, 6.750, inclusive=False) | 
                          bos['mu_yield'].between(89.000, 90.00, inclusive=False), 0, 1)
```

Comment: Got the below error                                                                                                                   
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_35620/2774411961.py in <module>
----> 1 bos['Target'] = np.where((bos['Bostwick'] < 5.000) | (bos['Bostwick'] > 6.750)) | ((bos['mu_yield'] < 89.00) | (bos['mu_yield'] > 90.00), 0, 1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: @Dhanush - what is `print (bos['Bostwick'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: [5.5, 7.75, 8.0, 6.75, 6.5]

Comment: @Dhanush - Can you test now? Both answers was changed and tested.